# Facebook like button not working on custom post type in wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I'm having trouble getting the facebook like button to work on custom post types in wordpress.

The code I'm using:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:25px"></iframe>
```

It registers the like on the site, but nothing updates on facebook.

Not sure what the problem is, think it may have something to do with the permalink, but everything I've tried doesn't work.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

2 Best Plugins are available for facebook like for custom post type

1. [Facebook Like Buttton](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-button/)
2. [Another good plugin for facebook like](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-button-plugin/)

You just have to: download it --> install it --> select type(POST) --> where to display (bottom of post)

OR if you interested for custom Facebook like "code" then [Go here](http://mashable.com/2010/05/07/wordpress-facebook-like-buttons/).

I hope this will help you out! :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but it doesn't really address the problem. It works fine adding like buttons to regular posts (i.e. in the slider above) just not Custom post types. BTW have already tried the first plugin with no success.